# php / html coding style

Tags: php, html, coding-style

Variant 1:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++) {
?>
    <p>some text</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Variant 2:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
     echo '<p>some text</p>';
}
?>
```

There is differnce between this coding styles in performance? or this is just a matter of taste?

Comment: Variant 3: [Alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Variant 2 causes more headaches due to excessive quoting, but mostly it's a matter of readability and personal preference.

Comment: It's really a matter of taste, use what you think is the most readable (for myself it's variant 2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taste. There's also a **[third one](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)**, which is considered more readable:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) : ?>
    <p>Some Text</p>
<?php endFor; ?>
```

Comment: @Repox I appreciate your concern, but since there's no real difference, and I (at least) find it more readable this way. I'd prefer if it stayed that way.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is the good coding standard. We should avoid echoing the html inside the php

Good standard

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) : ?>
    <p>Some Text</p>
<?php endFor; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of taste, but I would avoid variant 2.

It is similar to things like indentation: there is no set rule, but this one is, in my opinion, the most readable:

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) : ?>
<p>Some Text</p>
<?php endFor; ?>
```

This, I believe, is also what is used the majority of the time because, as Kalai says:

> "We should avoid echoing the html inside the php".

Answer (score 1):

If You don't want to escape `<?php ?>` then You should use `print` instead of `echo`. Print function is faster than `echo` (which is not actualy  a function but special syntax).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow Zend coding standards http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.html

Comment: A good link, but what do they suggest in this case?